# Plot swath data on shape file in python without regridding the data

Tags: python

I have a csv file containing swath data which has four parameters: date, flux, latitude, longitude. I want to plot this swath data on a shape file of India without regridding. I didn't find any solution which was done without regridding. A [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfF28GCq4SDm_A2I5QZAmxAmo0ACM1nn/view?usp=sharing) containing a small part of my data.

I tried with pyresample module. But it is really troublesome to do it for every hour as my actual data contains 300 000 rows.